# Navigations after authentication

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, navigation

I'm newbie to React native. I created an app and authetication process worked fine. After navigate to the dashboard, can I use navigations inside of the dashboard normally without user login condition?
For example,

```
   const navigation=useNavigation();
   <TouchableOpacity loading={loading} onPress={()=>{navigation.navigate("Dash",{screen:"places"})}} >
     <Text style={styles.signup}>Places</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
```

This is navigation routings on my app

```
export function Authscreens(){
       return(
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Authload">
          <Stack.Screen name="Authload" component={Authload} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={SignUp} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Reset" component={Reset} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          <Stack.Screen name="Dash" component={Main} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
        );

    }

    export function Dash(){
      return(
          <Stack.Navigator>

            <Stack.Screen name="places" component={places} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
            <Stack.Screen name="Cars" component={Cars} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
          </Stack.Navigator>

      );
    }
```

I already created a user login requirement for dashboard when authentication.

```
export default function Authload({ navigation }){
      const auth=getAuth();
        onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user) => {
            if (user) {
              return(navigation.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [{ name: 'Dash' }],
              }))
            } else {
              return(navigation.reset({
                index: 0,
                routes: [{ name: 'Login' }],
              }))
            }
          })
    }
```

I want to know that what is the method I can navigate inside dashboard items

Answer (score 0):

For Navigation You can use

```
navigation.navigate("YourComponent", {param})
// Or You can use push method
navigation.push("YourComponent", {param})
```